# Set first and last date for 10 months

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to write a code in cakephp to auto set the first and last date of months for 10 particular months fetched from a loop. Below is the form screenshot.

What I need: If the month is June from date should be 01/06/2016 and to date will be 30/06/2016 by default allowing the user to change the date. Here other months and year should be disabled. Similarly, if month is July it should be 01/07/2017 to 31/07/2016.

This should continue for 10 months from the current month. Below is the script

```
<script>
  //jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $(".last_from_date").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      changeMonth: false,
      maxDate: '0M',
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: '1900:2020'
    });
    $(".last_to_date").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      changeMonth: true,
      maxDate: '0M',
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: '1900:2020'
    });

    $('.abc').click(function () {
      alert($(this).attr("id"));
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      var a = id.split("-");
      var year = $.trim(a[0]);
      alert(year);
      var month = $.trim(a[1]);
      alert(month);

      var dat = new Date('1 ' + month + year);
      alert(dat.getMonth() + 1);
      //           alert(LastDayOfMonth(year,month));
      //            alert(x);
      //            $("#datepicker").datepicker("setMonth", newDate);


      var currentTime = new Date(dat);
      // First Date Of the month 
      var startDateFrom = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth(), 1);
      //// Last Date Of the Month 
      var startDateTo = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth() + 1, 0);
      $("#last_from_date_" + id).datepicker({

        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        minDate: startDateFrom,
        maxDate: startDateTo
      });
    });

  });
</script>
```

Image of form with records

[image]

Each row has a class "abc" and the from and to boxes are datepickers.

ERROR: I'm unable to set dates to these.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly how to write that in javascript but as you say this is a cakephp app in php in generall it works like this if you know the year and the month:

> $firstdateofMonth = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$year-$month-1"));
>
> $lastdateofMonth = date("Y-m-t", strtotime("$year-$month-1"));

("t" is always the last day of a given month).